# На форме WPF, пропадает указатель мыши

Tags: wpf, xaml

При наведении курсора на контроллы, например на TextBlockИ, находящиеся в расчерченном виде таблицы GridE пропадает указатель мыши.

```
<Grid Margin="5,0,5,5">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>                                                
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>    

  <TextBlock Text="V1:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="tbkV1_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
  <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Код для воспроизведения ошибки:

```
<Grid>
<TabControl Margin="0,125,0,64">
        <TabItem x:Name="tiFlowmeters" Header="Поверка расходомера" GotFocus="TiFlowmeters_GotFocus">
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <WrapPanel Height="504" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="#FF008E95">
                        <!--Прибор 1-->
                        <Grid Height="520" Background="#FFF2FFFF" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="chbDeviceF1" Content="Прибор 1" Margin="5,2,5,0" Click="ChbDeviceF1_Click"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Cursor="None" Margin="0,0,0,-7" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chbDeviceF1}">

                                    <TextBlock Text="Номер прибора:" Margin="5,2,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="tbDeviceNumberF1" Height="22" Margin="5,0,5,5" TextChanged="TbDeviceNumberF1_TextChanged"/>
                                    <Grid Height="27" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="ID прибора:" Margin="1,4,93,7"/>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="tbDeviceIdF1" Margin="74,1,0,4" TextChanged="TbDeviceIdF1_TextChanged"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Объём:" FontSize="14" Margin="5,5,5,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <Grid Margin="5,0,5,5">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Измеренные показатели:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="V1:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkV1_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="V2:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkV2_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Vизм:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkV_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Образцовые показатели:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="V1о:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkVo1_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="V2o:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkVo2_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Vобр:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkVo_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Результирующие показатели:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Ev:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkEv_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="%" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Eдопуст. :  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkEd_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="%" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10"/>

                                    </Grid>

                                    <TextBlock Text="Расход:" FontSize="14" Margin="5,5,5,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <Grid Margin="5,0,5,5">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="21*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="21*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Измеренные показатели:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="F1:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkF1_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3/ч" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="F2:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkF2_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3/ч" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Образцовые показатели:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Fобр:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkFo_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="М3/ч" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Результирующие показатели:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>


                                        <TextBlock Text="Ef1:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkEf1_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="%" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="Ef2:  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkEf2_1" Text="Значение" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="%" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnToTableFlowmeter1" Content="Внести в таблицу" Margin="5,5,5,0" Click="BtnToTableFlowmeter1_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
     </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Если судить по представленному коду, то всё в порядке. Мышка пропадает, когда вы запускаете приложение или когда направляете курсор на элементы в дизайнере?

Comment: @alladuh, когда запускаю приложение, причём основной Grid, в котором находится эта "табличка" первоначально неактивен (IsEnabled = false) и с указателем всё нормально, и как только он и все дочерние элементы становятся активными, при наведении на Grid(уже таблицу) указатель пропадает..

Comment: есть возможность опубликовать минимальный код для воспроизведения ошибки? Потому что сделать выводы из того, что есть, трудно

Comment: @alladuh, пару минут

Comment: @alladuh, есть.

Comment: Так у вас же стоит `Cursor="None"` для `StackPanel`

Comment: O_o  Даже не заметил... жесть. Видимо нужно идти отдыхать..

Answer (score 0):

Особо развёрнутый ответ дать трудно.

Следует убрать `Cursor="None"` в `StackPanel`